# getActivity in Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I'm having trouble with getActivity() in Activity. It says can't resolve method getActivity(). I'm using it to make onClick in recyclerView.

Here is my code

```
 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
 mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), this));
```

What should I change getActivity with? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared your code inside of an `Activity`. Therefore you can simply use `this` to reference the `Activity` you are in.

```
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, this));
```

Answer (score 1):

change it to

`this`

`this` is a reference to the class your in, like `MainActivity.this`

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to implements the recyclerclicklistener. After I implements the method and change

```
getActivity
```

to

```
this
```

it worked fine

```
extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters like this:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, mRecyclerView));
```

Or for detail information you can refer this bolg :-
[Android - RecyclerView: Implementing single.](https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/android-recyclerview-implementing-single-item-click-and-long-press-part-ii-b43ef8cb6ad8)

Answer (score 0):

All of the mentioned answers are correct. However, sometimes **'this'** can't referenced as your Activity ,mostly when we try to pass it from inside one of callback methods like :

```
view.setOnClickListener(v->showToast(this));
```

In such cases ,pass the activity using the whole name of the class like this :

```
view.setOnClickListener(v->showToast(Sample.this));
```